# Boost Polygon with indexed geometry

Tags: c++, boost, polygon, boost-geometry

I need to make some polygon computation on 2D plan. Typically, isInside operation.

I found boost::Polygon API but my points are inside a single big array.
That's I call indexed geometry.
See http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/

So my best way is just to boost::Polygon and give to it my array + indices of points to use.

The objective is just to don't copy my million of points (because they are shared at least by two polygons).

I don't know if API allows it ( or I need to inherit my own class :-( ).
Maybe, someone know another API (inside boost or other).

Thanks

Documentation

- within demo : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html

Comment: I know it might not be sufficient answer for you but I would recomment two things:
- if you work with such big data, then before sending it anywhere outside you could try to implement some basic validation by yourself, for your case - it's known that "isInside" operation will be false if any pair of segments from two polygons intersects, you might try to implement [intersection check](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/) -if any occurs you know that isInside is false
- try to [use PgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-geometric.html)

Comment: It always works better to show some code. Even if it's just a simplified example (SSCCE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost Geometry allows for adapted user-defined data types.

Specifically, C arrays are adapted here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/c_array.hpp

I have another answer up where I show how to use Boost Geometry algorithms on a direct C array of structs (in that case I type punned using tuple as the point type): [How to calculate the convex hull with boost from arrays instead of setting each point separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522967/how-to-calculate-the-convex-hull-with-boost-from-arrays-instead-of-setting-each/33546508#33546508) (the other answers show alternatives that may be easier if you can afford to copy some data).

The relevant algorithms would be:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within.html
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/disjoint.html

Comment: I will see your link soon ! But you reply to my question: boost has all to make what I want (without inherit class). Thanks